# ¿Cómo hago que un archivo.js sea ejecutable desde windows?

Tags: javascript

Siempre me ha surgido la curiosidad de ver cómo se puede ejecutar un archivo.js desde windows, pero cuando creo un archivo.js con el siguiente código:

```
w=window.open("","","width=300,height=300")
```

Me da el siguiente error:

> 'Window' no está definido.
>   Y si cambio el código a este:

```
w=open("","","width=300,height=300")
```

Me da este error:

> Se esperaba un objeto.

¿Como hago el objeto?

Comment: Incluso usando node, el código que estas tratando de ejecutar tiene sentido solo en un contexto web. Ese código está pensado en utilizarse desde un navegador, no desde lado servidor

Comment: Lo sé, es una función que tiene PHP para amplificar sus funciones, pudiendo agregar canvas y contexto 2d, pero lo que quería averiguar es como crear un objeto.

Comment: la respuesta es: no puedes hacer lo que quieres hacer, Windows no entiende Javascript. El objeto `window` es una API que existe solo en el browser (ni siquiere en node). Si quieres hacer una APP en js, hechale un vistaso a Electron. github.com/electron/electron

Comment: Si lo que quieres es hacer una app ejecutable en nuevas versiones de Windows (8, 8.1, 10) te recomiendo WinJS -> http://try.buildwinjs.com/ que es el framework de Microsoft para crear apps utilizando JavaScript. Saludos

Comment: mas si ya tienes el archivo.js y deseas visualizarlo mediante consola, usa el comando node, previamente instalado en tu computador, así: `node archivo.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este es el primer ejercicio que debe hacer cualquier programador con los lenguajes nuevos. Se trata de un comando que imprime un "hola mundo!" en una ventana. Lo dejo acá:

```
WScript.Echo("¡Hola mundo!")
```

Ah y si se quiere almacenar una variable se hace así:

```
texto="¡Hola mundo!"
WScript.Echo(texto)
```

Se debe de ejecutar desde el ordenador, haciendo doble click sobre él.

Alternativamente se puede crear una shell para ejecutar los comandos de forma más personalizada. Acá va el window create popup (En este caso se preguntaría por la respuesta):

```
shell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
option=shell.Popup("Cuerpo de la ventana.",0,"Título de la ventana.",4)
if(option==6){
  shell.Popup("Texto cuando se clickea sí.",0,"Mi primer script.")
}else{
  shell.Popup("Texto cuando se clickea no.",0,"Mi primer script.")
}
```

Comment: No conocía de dicha sintaxis para imprimir en JavaScript

Comment: Te invito a probarlo, mete ambos párrafos, desactiva "ocultar las extensiones" en las opciones de carpeta y nombra un archivo con el nombre que tu quieras terminado en '.js'.

Comment: Pues lo he probado y me deja este error **VM54:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: WScript is not defined
    at <anonymous>:2:1**

Comment: No, debes de ejecutarlo desde el ordenador, haciendo doble click en el archivo. La sintaxis es muy similar a la de javascript, o al menos el for funciona igual.

Answer (score 6):

Para ejecutar código JavaScript necesitas un intérprete de JavaScript. Lo habitual es que el JavaScript se ejecute dentro de un navegador web, que ya incluyen dicho intérprete. Otra forma de ejecutar muy en uso últimamente es mediante [node.js](https://nodejs.org/es/). Node.js te permite ejecutar código JavaScript directamente desde la consola (o desde le explorador de archivos, o cualquier otro método para lanzar la ejecución del fichero JavaScript) sin tener que cargar el código JavaScript en el navegador.

Sin embargo, no es lo mismo. Así como el lenguaje JavaScript es el mismo en ambos casos, no son lo mismo los objetos que tienes disponibles desde un principio. Por ejemplo, el objeto `window` de tu código es un objeto de JavaScript específico de los navegadores que representa la ventana del navegador. Node.js no ofrece ese objeto dado que el código JavaScript no se ejecuta en el entorno de una ventana de navegador.

Por tanto, el código que has escrito se debería ejecutar en un navegador. Para ello necesitas crear una página HTML que incluya tu código.

NOTA: Internamente Node.js contiene el intérprete de JavaScript de Chrome, el [V8](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_(motor_JavaScript)).

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**:

Parece que hay más opciones:

**Windows nativo**

Windows permite ejecutar de forma nativa scripts de tipo [JScript](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript) mediante la utilidad [CScript](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb490887.aspx).

Para ello parece que bastaría con:

```
Cscript.exe archivo.js
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que:

- JScript no es puramente JavaScript, es un dialecto y tendrá ciertas diferencias. No podría resumirte las diferencias dado que es un lenguaje que no he usado y por lo que he visto cambia según versiones.
- Aunque JavaScript es un lenguaje estandarizado, como he comentado más arriba ciertos objetos como el objeto 'window' no tienen por qué estar disponibles en ciertos entornos.

**Java**

Sorprendentemente Java incluye una funcionalidad para ejecutar diferentes tipos scripts entre los que se incluye JavaScript. Una vez instalado Java se usaría así:

```
jrunscript -f archivo.js
```

También puedes pasarle código directamente la línea del comando:

```
jrunscript -e "print('Hola mundo')"
```

O usar el modo interactivo

```
jrunscript
```

**NOTA FINAL**: Después de todo esto, hay que volver hacer hincapié en que en los ejemplos que código que pones usas el objeto `window`. Como se ha dicho antes, ese objeto solo lo tendrás disponible cuando el código JavaScript se ejecute dentro de un navegador, ya que el objeto `window` no es más que un interfaz para que los scripts JavaScript se comuniquen con el navegador. Por tanto, aunque puedas ejecutar JavaScript nativamente con Windows no creo que tengas el objeto `window` disponible.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61405/discussion-on-answer-by-sanzante-como-hago-que-un-archivo-js-sea-ejecutable-des).

Answer (score 0):

Prueba creando un archivo **.html**, por ejemplo:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>HTML file with JS</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="btn">Abrir ventana</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('btn')
        .addEventListener('click', function() {
            window.open("","","width=300,height=300");
        });
  </script>
</body>
```

Al hacer doble-click sobre el archivo debería abrirse la aplicación por defecto, normalmente un navegador.

Comment: Hablo de un archivo.js, no de un archivo.html, aunque bueno...

Answer (score -1):

Si lo que tienes es un archivo "nombrearchivo.js", para poder ver tu ejemplo corriendo, es creando un archivo html (ejemplo.html) y verlo en tu  navegador

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>TypeScript Greeter</title></head>
    <body>
        <script src="nombrearchivo.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si ya has respondido una vez, intenta editar tu primera respuesta y adaptarlo a que pregunta el OP.

Comment: no es bien visto dejar múltiples respuestas a la misma pregunta, borra una de estas y edita la otra para poner lo que hace falta

Comment: Lo mismo, hablo de un archivo.js, pero bueno gracias por tu aporte ;)